# Can I define a Ruby function for an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Can I define some Ruby function (other than JavaScript) in the onclick event for a radio button?

For example, could I use something like this?

```
<%= radio_button(count, voting.vote_count, :onclick => "if voting.nominees.eql?(selected.nominees) voting.update_attribute('vote_count',voting.vote_count+1 )")
```

Comment: Can we start tagging questions like this with `javascript-misunderstanding`? There's a lot of them lately... O_O

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the Ruby is running on the server and the JavaScript is running on the browser.

By the time the click happens, the Ruby program has finished running.

The only way to get the Ruby function to run would be to make a new HTTP request to the server. The [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html) object lets you do this from JavaScript. To achieve it without JavaScript you would need to do some trickery.

```
<form action="..." method="post">
  <div>
    <button type="submit"> 
      <img src="looks-like-a-radio-button.png" alt="vote">
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" name="vote" value="whatever">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can i increase the vote_count without the onclick event.
Actually i want to increase the vote_count when the user select the answer

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible without Javascript, and even if it was what would stop the user from running any arbitrary code that she wanted?